# No log files to process endeca

Tags: runtime-error, endeca, reportgenerator

I want to  create a diary report with endeca, so I have log server running at 15010 [port], but when I start [WeeklyReportGenerator] seems something is wrong I think because I have an error with log server, I check log and this is error:

```
Oct 12, 2012 10:19:17 AM com.endeca.forge.base.Pipeline$Engine$1 handle
WARNING: Error in pipeline: No log files to process
Oct 12, 2012 10:19:17 AM com.endeca.rg.components.input.FileSystemMultiInput$Engine$Statistics log
INFO: LogFileInput/FileSystemInput/com.endeca.rg.components.input.FileSystemMultiInput: Progress: 1/1 (100%), 0:00:00 remaining
Oct 12, 2012 10:19:17 AM com.endeca.rg.ReportGenerator main
SEVERE: Unable to proceed
Pipeline execution interrupted by exception
No log files to process
java.lang.RuntimeException: No log files to process
    at com.endeca.rg.components.input.LogFileInput$Substitution$1$Engine.portClosed(LogFileInput.java:269)
```

Some clue about what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The reporting processes need log files in order to produce reports.  By default, no log messages are sent to the log server.

If you look at the orange reference app (http://:8006/endeca_jspref ) you'll see that it does implement logging. If you look at the logging_functions.jsp, you can see a good basic implementation of how to send log messages ( C:\Endeca\ToolsAndFrameworks\11.1.0\reference\endeca_jspref\logging_functions.jsp )

If you're using the Assembler API, it will handle most logging for you. Make sure you have the correct hostname and port configured. If you need to extend or replace the logging, look for the com.endeca.infront.navigation.event.LogServerAdapter in the assembler-context.xml.